# Why doesnt my html show up in my ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to add replies to the microposts found in this application https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed

I think I figured out all of the model and controller stuff but that is besides the point.

When I try to add a reply link to app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb. it never works.

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <p>this text doesnt show up!</p>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to "reply", new_comment_path(:micropost_id => comment) %> |

  <p> why isnt this working!!?</p>
</li>
```

as you can see I have tried on lines 3 13 and 15 to add a basic text or a reply link. It never shows up. am I doing this wrong? What format should I put a reply link/even basic text I want to show up in?

Here is my micropost controller code

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

and here is my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create 
    @comment = @micropost.comments.new(params[:comment]) 
    if @comment.save 
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      redirect_to @user
    end 
  end 

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Any chance you aren't rendering the partial?

Comment: I understand what a partial is, but where should it be rendered? which one should be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably something like this in your index.html.erb

```
<% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  <%= render partial: 'micropost', locals: { :micropost => micropost} %>
<% end %>
```

The partial name is just what the file is called minus the _ and .html.erb. Locals passes the variables to the partial